# how to write this code in ? : operator in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

Can you help me to understand the if conditions in operators

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PrimeNumber {
    boolean flag = true;
    public boolean findPrimeNumber(int num){
        for(int i = 2;i<num;++i){
            flag = (num%i==0)?(false):true;
            if(num%i==0){/* Here i want to ?: */
                flag = false;
                break;
            }else{
                flag = true;
            }
        }return flag;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number:");
        boolean flag =new PrimeNumber().findPrimeNumber(sc.nextInt());
        if(flag){
            System.out.println("Prime Number !!!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not a Prime !!!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `flag = (num%i==0)` is all you need for that first one. It is common to think it's necessary to explicitly set a boolean when the result is already a boolean - don't do that please :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go;

```
public class PrimeNumber {
    boolean flag = true;
    public boolean findPrimeNumber(int num){
        for(int i = 2;i<num;++i){
            flag = (num%i==0) ?  false: true;
        }return flag;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number:");
        boolean flag =new PrimeNumber().findPrimeNumber(sc.nextInt());
        if(flag){
            System.out.println("Prime Number !!!");
        }else{
        System.out.println("Not a Prime !!!");
        }

    }
}
```

I guess I might misunderstood something, if so tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your lines as per your code:

**Line 1:**

```
flag = (num%i==0)?(false):true;//This one is almost equivalent to below
```

**Line 2:**

```
if(num%i==0){/* Here i want to ?: */
    flag = false;
    break;
}else{
    flag = true;
}
```

**However, you cannot have break when using ternary operator.**, if that's what you are wondering.